# Pass Multiple Arguments in npm command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to pass argument in my npm command and use that argument in my script

Example:

npm run test -b chrome -e QA

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "something.js ./xyz/abc/cdf --something \"{\\\"browser\\\": \\\"<process.argv[2]>\\\"}\""
}
```

I am not sure, how to access  in my script.

Please advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `something.js` you can access the process arguments by `process.argv`.

It will be an array of x elements, where the first two are the executable running your script and the second is a path to the script that is being ran.

Try `console.log(process.argv);` to see whats up.

In your specific example you should remove the escaped `"` characters to get it working, like so:

**running node in terminal**

`node somethings.js ./xyz/abc/cdf --something "{\\\"browser\\\": \\\"<process.argv[2]>\\\"}"`

Results in:

`[ '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/Users/user/Documents/test.js',
  './xyz/abc/cdf',
  '--something',
  '{\\"browser\\": \\"<process.argv[2]>\\"}' ]`

---

**package.json script**

`"scripts": {
    "test": "node test.js"
  },`

*Note: add node as the executable in the test script*

Running `npm run test -b chrome -e QA`

Results in:

`[ '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/Users/user/Documents/test.js',
  'chrome',
  'QA' ]`

If you'd like to get the `-b` and `-e` arguments in there too, add `--`. Like so:

`npm run test -- -b chrome -e QA`

Results in

`[ '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/Users/user/Documents/test.js',
  '-b',
  'chrome',
  '-e',
  'QA' ]`

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help :)