# How to pass multiple environment variables in Cypress tests?

Tags: environment-variables, cypress

In my Cypress test, I am trying to pass multiple environment variables via the command line with the below command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --env url=https://example.cypress.io/todo,height=900
```

According to Cypress documentation (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env):

> Multiple values must be separated by a comma, not a space.

So I'm not sure why an error is being thrown.

Below is the error message I am getting:

> CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
> https://example.cypress.io/todo%20height=900
>
> The response we received from your web server was:
> 404: Not Found

I understand the URL is picking up the `height` value, but I'm following the Cypress documentation, so I don't know why it isn't being passed in as a second variable.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, & how it can be resolved?

Comment: I think this has the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595980/pass-multiple-arguments-in-npm-command

Comment: Can you share your cypress code that calls `cy.visit`?